# $routeProvider (templateUrl) и $route.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Здравствуйте!
Возникла проблема с данным кодом:

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $route, $routeParams, $templateCache) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'index.php',
                controller: 'clearRoute'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                controller:'clearRoute',
                templateUrl: 'contact.php'
            })
            .when('/post', {
                controller:'clearRoute',
                templateUrl: 'post.php'
            })
            .when('/post/:postId', {
                templateUrl: function(params){
                    return '/post.php?post=' + params.postId;
                },
                controller: 'clearRoute'
            })
            .when('/404', {
                controller:'clearRoute',
                template: "<h1>Page not found</h1>"
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/404' });
    }]);
    app.controller('clearRoute', function($scope, $route, $templateCache) {
        var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
        $templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
        $route.reload();
    });
```

Проблема возникает с данной частью

```
when('/post/:postId', {
            templateUrl: function(params){
                return '/post.php?post=' + params.postId;
            },
            controller: 'clearRoute'
        })
```

Мне нужно передать каким-то образом параметр роута postId, решение нашел, но как кажется мне, из-за вот этого решения ( function(params() {} ) ничего и не получается. Вообщем, сама проблема: когда я пытаюсь перейти на адрес "http://site/#/post/423" - страницу выводит, всё хорошо. Но помимо этого, мне надо чтобы когда эта страница подгружалась происходила функция $route.reload() т.е. страница грузилась заново (например: если я сделал изменения, они были видны без полного обновления страницы ( http://site/#/post/423 ). Для этих действий я подключил контроллер с кодом:

```
app.controller('clearRoute', function($scope, $route, $templateCache) {
    var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
    $templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
    $route.reload();
});
```

Но с этим контроллером страница просто умирает, и надо просто перезагружать вкладку.
Вопрос: есть ли какой-то иной (если можно не сильно многострочный код) для передачи роутПараметров в templateUrl да и перезагрузки сохраненного темплейта в роуте ( $route.reload() );
Спасибо!)

Comment: а в консоль что валится?

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать в итоге, поясните пожалуйста.